# Get the time out of datetime.timedelta list

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta, data-processing

I have calculated the time difference using

```
datetime.strptime ('End Time', FMT) - datetime.strptime ('Start Time', FMT)
```

and got the list of strings of the format  `datetime.timedelta(seconds=1535)`

I am stuck on how to get the seconds only out of the list of strings, as the object is not subscriptable,  and also if there is a way to calculate the time difference in minutes/hours?

Answer (score 1):

```
(datetime.strptime ('End Time', FMT) - datetime.strptime ('Start Time', FMT)).total_seconds()
```

should do the trick, to get seconds, at least since python 3.2. Please refer to documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta).

To get other time units, you could easily calculate them, or use time module, i.e.:

```
from time import strftime
from time import gmtime

strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime(td.total_seconds()))
```

where `td` is your timedelta object.